Stochastic processes with elegant closed form distributions
A Poisson process $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ of rate $\lambda$ has the well-known closed form distribution $\mathbb{P}(X_t=k)=\frac{(\lambda t)^ke^{-\lambda t}}{k!}$.
Yule processes, with rates $\lambda_n=n\lambda$, also have a nice closed form solution for their distribution: $\mathbb{P}(X_t=k)=e^{-\lambda t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{k-1}$ if we start the birth process with one individual - or the negative binomial distribution if we start with more.
These are both examples of simple birth processes, and the Poisson process is also an example of a renewal process. I'm looking to collect other examples of simple birth processes or renewal processes that have elegant closed form solutions for their distributions. Counting processes or CTMCs more generally if they have elegant solutions are welcome too (though avoiding simple things like the independent Bernoulli trials counting process - which pretty obviously follows a binomial distribution)

'that have elegant form" : does this one enters in this category ?

Yeah that's a good example thanks. I'm mainly looking for new examples for explaining this stuff that aren't just those two - that you find as the examples in almost all material online already.
